# Installing 'WCF HTTP Activation' on Windows Vista fails?

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-vista

This is only remotely development related, but basically I wanted to install the MS Azure SDK which relies on an installed IIS 7, ASP.Net but also a working installation of the 'WCF HTTP Activation' component.

Now following the [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179419.aspx), I always get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing or what I should do? The error message is not very self-explaining and I am a tad lost here.. Software version wise Vista is SP2, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 & .Net 3.5 SP1 is also installed..

**Update:** *Oh and the Visual Studio 2010 / .Net 4 beta. Might the later have something to do with it?*

Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oook here's the deal: when you install the .Net 4.0 beta, for some reason it also overwrites at least one of your .Net 3.0 (WCF) files, at least on 64bit systems, namely

"*c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\SMConfigInstaller.EXE*".

So the bad part is, with this new version in place you cannot longer enable the "WCF HTTP Activation" Feature of Vista and Win7 and even worse, uninstalling .Net 4 beta **does not** restore the original version.

Meh.

So the only *manual* workaround is to get your hands on an actual pre .net 4 beta version of the folder above and restore the file(s) manually.

-J

Comment: How did you delete the file? I keep getting access denied.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this where the machine.config file was corrupted; some component in .NET modified it and inserted a null byte somewhere. If you have powershell installed, you can quickly check the validity of the config like so:

```
[xml](gc $env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config)
```

It will fail to parse if corrupted.

-Oisin

Comment: There ain't a parsing error, but the output looks like this:

PS C:\Users\joerg> [xml](gc $env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\confi
g\machine.config)

xml                        #comment                   configuration
---                        --------                   -------------
                                                      configuration

Comment: Err that looks messed up. Basically it doesn't fail.. in terms of exception/error, but just a blank table.

Answer (score 0):

CAUTION!!! I would caution against ever messing with framework files manually like the above poster suggested...that's just asking for trouble.

I had a similar issue which I have now solved without touching with any framework files.

Background: I was trying to get my IIS hosted WCF service running with a net.tcp endpoint on Windows 7. I had installed IIS after installing VS2010 beta2. Although my service was working over HTTP, when my client tried to connect over net.tcp it would get the completely ridiculous error: "FatalExecutionEngineError was detected" No help at all!!!

I think the error was being thrown because my WCF client was unable to connect to the server. Normally a connection-related exception should be thrown, but I suspect that I got the fatal error because my service request consisted of a custom Message with a Stream.

Anyways, I finally got it working and I believe the key was to re-install the WCF HTTP activation along with aspnet.

1. Go to the Control Panel
2. Click on Programs and Features
3. Click on Turn Windows Features on/off
4. Uncheck Microsoft.Net Framework 3.5.1 (and the two options beneath)
5. Click OK to restart
6. Follow steps 1-3 then check all 3 options and restart

I then registered IIS by running the following (as admin):
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru

Sorry for the long story, but I wanted all the "key words" in there for google to help other folks that might run into the same or similar problem.